# `sync_partition_metadata` in presto as a result returning query

Tags: sql, presto

Is there a way to make this query work?

```
SELECT "result" AS "result"
FROM (CALL system.sync_partition_metadata('schema', 'table', 'ADD')) AS "virtual_table"
LIMIT 1000;
```

this is the error I get:

> presto error: line 3:18: mismatched input '.'. Expecting: '(', ')',
> ',', 'AS', 'CROSS', 'EXCEPT', 'FETCH', 'FULL', 'GROUP', 'HAVING',
> 'INNER', 'INTERSECT', 'JOIN', 'LEFT', 'LIMIT', 'MATCH_RECOGNIZE',
> 'NATURAL', 'OFFSET', 'ORDER', 'RIGHT', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'UNION',
> 'WHERE', 'WINDOW', ,

Comment: Do you receive any error when you ran this query or it is not giving expected behaviour ?

Comment: Have you tried running just CALL system.sync_partition_metadata('schema', 'table', 'ADD') ?

Comment: Doing that works, and returns `true`. The issue is I wanted to capture that output as a table, so it can be visualised in superset.